# return element.parentNode in iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a jquery-like utilities library for me, just the things I mostly use from jQuery.

I have the following code:

```
function jLib(selector) {

  this.elements = selector.nodeType ? [ selector ] : document.querySelectorAll(selector);


  this.each = function(cb) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {           
        var el = this.elements[i];
        cb.call(this, el);
    }
  };


  this.parent = function() {
    this.each(function(element) {
       return element.parentNode;
    });
  };

  this.addClass = function(className) {

        this.each(function(element) {
            className.split(' ').forEach(function(_className) {
                element.classList.add(_className);
            });
        });

        return this;
    };

}


new jLib('.has_parrent').parent().addClass('border');
```

I'm trying to loop trought the elements and then return element.parentNode, but as expected function exit when first return.

Can someone explain me please how to send the parent of the element so I can access other methods in my library?

```
new jLib('.has_parrent').parent().addClass('border');
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question, instead of a link to it.

Comment: "*as excepted*"???

Comment: If you want to write a jQuery like library, with chaining, you can't escape building a constructor or factory wrapping elements starting not only from a selector (as you did) but also from elements. You can look how it's done in jQuery (it's complex) or in similar libraries ([exemple](https://github.com/Canop/jacquerie/blob/master/src%2Finit.js#L15), it's complex too).

Comment: Your `each` function doesn't do anything with return values, so why do you `return` from your callback? Sounds like you actually wanted to implement `map`. Also your `parent` method doesn't `return` anything, so you can't expect it to be chainable

Comment: @Bergi the thing I want to achieve is to send the parentNode of the element, I use each inside the parent in case I have more element with same selector

Comment: @Hiero: Send… yes, but send *where*? As I said, you want `map` instead of `each`

Comment: @Bergi, return not send, sorry, so i can invoke other methods

Comment: @Hiero That's called "chaining". Read my previous comment. But Bergi is totally right in saying you should use `map` instead of `each` so that you can create an array of the parent elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `parent()` return a new `jLib` object containing the parent elements like

```js
function isArray(obj) {
  return Array.isArray(obj);
}

function jLib(selector) {
  this.elements = selector.nodeType ? [selector] : (isArray(selector) ? selector : document.querySelectorAll(selector));


  this.each = function(cb) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
      var el = this.elements[i];
      cb.call(this, el);
    }
  };


  this.parent = function() {
    var els = [].map.call(this.elements, function(element) {
      return element.parentNode;
    });

    return new jLib(els);
  };

  this.addClass = function(className) {

    this.each(function(element) {
      className.split(' ').forEach(function(_className) {
        element.classList.add(_className);
      });
    });

    return this;
  };

}


new jLib('.has_parrent').parent().addClass('border');
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="has_parrent">has parrent</div>
</div>

<div class="parent parent-2">
  <div class="has_parrent">has parrent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Protip: `Array.isArray` :-)

Comment: Nested ternary ? This starts to look like jQuery ^^